# Generate PDF in PHPDocumentor2?

Tags: phpdocumentor2

phpdoc -d lib/model -t /var/www/html/docs/ --template responsive

generates html docs fine.

I have upgraded to PHPDocumentor2 and cannot find the command for outputing to PDF. The old way for 1.x doesn't not work in the new version.

Can someone tell me how to do this or point me to the documentation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems that [PDF creation is implemented](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/releases/tag/v2.3.0) but there are no PDF output templates yet.

Comment: This release has initial pdf creation  [link](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/tree/v2.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

In the new version 2. * yet there is no such pdf template.

there are only http://www.phpdoc.org/templates

template selection

```
phpdoc --template="clean" --template="checkstyle" -d .
```

### -----------------------------------------------------------

**BTW** I use the older version (1.4.4) I wanted to save to pdf.

```
phpdoc -o PDF:default:default -t ./docs -d ./
```

But created an bad document. Maybe version 1.4.4 does not work with PHP 5.5.11 on the issue in PDF format.

I managed in version 1.4.4  only generate HTML.

```
phpdoc -o HTML:frames:earthli -t ./docs -d ./
```

So I went back to version 2 * and I wait pdf template.